# Visual Studio execute command line Kaspersky scan

Tags: c#, security, command-line, visual-studio-2013

What I need to do is run a Kaspersky Endpoint 10 scan from my visual studio web form.

I'm creating an Image Uploader via telerik:RadAsyncUpload. Once the file is uploaded into the TempFolder, I need to run a command line scan before I can save the uploaded file to a TargetFolder. How do I go about doing this? And how would I be able to return any results to Visual Studio, or even know if a file was suspicious and quarantined?

Thanks in advance. If this is too vague, please let me know of how I can clarify my questions.

Comment: a cmd may only return an "status"-int . What you can do is when doing the scan per cmd, you need to create a log and then in your c#-app read that log out.

Comment: take a look at taht: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Do you mean by copying the CL results to a .txt or something along those lines? Or this something I should be able to access in Kaspersky?

Comment: To run the scanner from the command line you'll use Process.Start.  @Alexis' comment is correct about logging and reading the log, unless Kaspersky has a documented set of status values you can use instead when the process terminates.

Comment: Is it possible to use Process.Start to first change the directory.. and then execute the scan command? it would be two commands. @AlexisPeters

Comment: why do you need to change a directory, you could use the absolute path of kaspersky's cmd. I can't help you with this, I'm not working on an Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexisPeters and @EricBurcham, this is what I came up with.

I ended up scripting the necessary commands to run the scan and it works 100%.

Here is my method:

```
public void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cmd.bat")
                {
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```